# Why do some non-empty strings evaluate to "false" in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, type-coercion

According to [this table in the ECMAScript standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.2), string values that have length 0 should be evaluated as boolean `false`.

How come, then, these statements evaluate to `true`?

```
"\t" == false
" " == false
"\n" == false
"     " == false
```

All those strings have a length greater than 0. For example:

[image: Not falsey]

While I understand that `"0"` evaluates to `false` because it can be coerced to a numeric `0`, I can't explain why these strings are falsey. What's going on?

(Obviously I can use `===` for a strict comparison, but in this case in my code, I need the loose comparison, however I wasn't expecting a non-empty string to be considered falsey.)

Comment: In which browser/environment are you seeing this behavior?

Comment: probably duplicated with this page of stackoverflow:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5634372/why-is-t-n-false-in-javascript

Comment: @vagueness Yeah, pretty much. It didn't show up in my searches, unfortunately.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are using *loose comparison*, which performs *type conversion*. Whenever you compare against a Boolean, both values are actually converted to numbers ([spec, steps 7 and 5](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3)). `false` is `0` and (surprisingly!)every string containing only white space characters is converted to `0` as well (when converted to a number) ([spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.3.1)):

> The MV of `StringNumericLiteral ::: StrWhiteSpace` is `0`.

---

> I wasn't expecting a non-empty string to be considered falsey

**Comparing** a value against a Boolean is very different from **converting** a value to a Boolean. "Falsy" means that the value is converted to `false` when converted to a Boolean. However, again, in your case the values are converted to numbers first.

Example:

```
Number("    ") // 0 ( == Number(false))
// vs
Boolean("    ") // true
```

Comment: @RobG: I only pointed out where Booleans are converted, but you are right, the way I phrased the sentence before creates other expectations. Updating :)